# Problems with sourcerer and a table

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, custom-module

Why if I try to generate a table in a custom html it doesn't show a table?, it appears everything in the same line and I don't know why. This is the code:

```
{source}
<?php
  $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query->select($db->quoteName(array('a.Nombre','a.Email','a.Pais','a.Google','a.Skype','a.Password')))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__chronoengine_chronoforms_datatable_Intercambios','a'));

  $db->setQuery($query);
  $options = $db->loadAssocList();~
?>

<p>
 <?php foreach( $options as $option ) { 
    $this_user_email = $option['Email']; 
    $this_user_skype = $option['Skype']; 
    this_user_name = $option['Nombre']; 
    $this_user_pais = $option['Pais'];
    $this_user_google = $option['Google'];
?>
</p>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Nivel</th>
            <th>Pais</th>
            <th>Votos</th>
            <th>Skype</th> 
            <th>Hangout</th>
            <th>FaceTime</th>
            <th>Correo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php print_r($this_user_name);?></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><?php print_r($this_user_pais);?> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> <?php print_r($this_user_skype);?></td>
            <td> <?php print_r($this_user_skype);?></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> <?php print_r($this_user_email);?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <?php } ?>
{/source}
```

Comment: How resulting HTML code looks like? Are all the table tags there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem being is that you are echoing a full table foreach result. Have a look at this updated code and let me know what the outcome is:

```
{source}
<?php
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('a.Nombre','a.Email','a.Pais','a.Google','a.Skype','a.Password')))
          ->from($db->quoteName('#__chronoengine_chronoforms_datatable_Intercambios','a'));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $options = $db->loadAssocList();
?>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Nivel</th>
            <th>Pais</th>
            <th>Votos</th>
            <th>Skype</th> 
            <th>Hangout</th>
            <th>FaceTime</th>
            <th>Correo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach( $options as $option ) 
            { 
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php print_r($option['Nombre']); ?></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php print_r($option['Pais']); ?> </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php print_r($option['Skype']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print_r($option['Google']); ?></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php print_r($option['Email']); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            } 
        ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
{/source}
```

There was also a missing `$` for one of your variables and a random `~` after the `$options variable.` I've also added `&nbsp;` for the blank table columns

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Sourcerer is oriented to add simple PHP snippets.

Even if it is possible, I would not recommend to anyone to develop a module inside a custom html module.

BTW: please, do not tell me you want to show this module inside an article. :-D

Answer (score 0):

if you use no editor, sourcerer strips all html tags.
Use `{source 0} .... {/source}` to prevent it.
[sourcerer tutorial](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer/tutorial#using-html-entities)